# How to change the TOC Font

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, fontspec, koma-script

My question:
Is it possible for the TOC to produce output using the Mathilde font?

At present the TOC produces output as:

```
          Contents

Falling.....................1
Rising......................5
```

The Chapter Subheadings are produced from the following code:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
font=\fontsize{45}{40}\selectfont\mdseries\mathilde
font=\fontsize{20}{15}
]{section}

\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont\fontspec{mathilde}}
```

This is an MWE of the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,british,twoside,openany,headings=small]{scrbook}

\usepackage{ms_mystyles}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=0pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocstyle=gobble]{chapter}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }

\RedeclareSectionCommand[ font=\fontsize{45} {40}\selectfont\mdseries\mathilde font=\fontsize{20}{15} ]{section}

   \setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont\fontspec{mathilde}}
 \begin{document}

        \tableofcontents

        \addchap{Tryout}
        \addsec{Simple Heading}
    \mainmatter
    \addchap{ONE}
    \addsec{Falling}
    \input{Some text}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Why you try to change the fontsize of your "Chapter Subheadings"  first to 45pt, then to 20pt (there is also a comma missing before the second `font` option) and then to 35pt?

Answer (score 3):

If the section entries in TOC should use Mathilde font:

```
\newfontfamily\mathilde{Mathilde}

\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [
    font=\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont\mdseries\mathilde,
    tocindent=0pt,
    tocentryformat=\mathildeintoc,
    %tocpagenumberformat=\mathildeintoc% if pagenumbers should also use mathilde
  ]{section}
\newcommand\mathildeintoc[1]{{\mathilde#1}}
```

[image]

Note that this needs KOMA-Script version 3.20 or newer.

Code:

```
\documentclass
  [12pt,open=any,headings=small]
  {scrbook}[2016/05/10]% needs version 3.20 or newer

\usepackage{lipsum} % to show dummy text 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\newfontfamily\mathilde{Mathilde}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocstyle=gobble]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [
    font=\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont\mdseries\mathilde,
    tocindent=0pt,
    tocentryformat=\mathildeintoc,
    %tocpagenumberformat=\mathildeintoc% if pagenumbers should also use mathilde
  ]{section}
\newcommand\mathildeintoc[1]{{\mathilde#1}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Tryout}
\addsec{Simple Heading}
\mainmatter
\addchap{ONE}
\addsec{Falling}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

---

If all section, subsection, subsubsection etc. entries in TOC should use Mathilde Font

```
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\mathilde}
```

Note that this does not change the font of chapter entries and the font of the pagenumbers for all entry levels.

```
\documentclass
  [12pt,open=any,headings=small]
  {scrbook}[2016/05/10]% needs version 3.20 or newer

\usepackage{lipsum} % to show dummy text 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\newfontfamily\mathilde{Mathilde}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocstyle=gobble]{chapter}% needs version 3.20 or newer
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [
    font=\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont\mdseries\mathilde,
    tocindent=0pt
]{section}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\mathilde}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Tryout}
\addsec{Simple Heading}
\mainmatter
\addchap{ONE}
\addsec{Falling}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: esdd - Thank you very much indeed for your very informative and useful answer. Mike